# Fetch Data from MYSql and display with radio button in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me how to fetch data from `mysql` and display it with radio button?

What I want is that, the user will input items into the database in a specific date. Those items will be displayed and will appear with radio button on its side. Another user will select from those items encoded, what will be approved and disapproved. There is no definite type of item. Items to be entered to database are different from each other and defined by user solely.

Can anyone provide me an example of how these things will be achieved??
Just give sample that would do same thing specified above. Even just the basic.

Thanks.

Comment: If when you click the button, is data shown in radio button's value or name, you should use jQuery events.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? You should first learn how to output radio buttons with values from PHP variables. Then look into prepared statements with PHP's mysqli to learn how to retrieve and/or store data in a database. After this, outputting radio buttons with data retrieved from mysqli is trivial.